# How to display current_user bio

Tags: user-meta

I'm displaying the current user's info on the front-end, but haven't been able to locate the correct hook for the bio, other than as an "author" hook.  Help?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [`wp_get_current_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) to find out which user is browsing the site.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
```

From there you'll use the `ID` to pull the user's metadata with [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID );

echo 'User Description: ' . $all_meta_for_user['description'] . '<br />';
```

The `description` key is probably what you're after.

---

As you pointed out, the [`WP_User`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php) already includes a few fields on it which may be duplicated in the user_meta, including `$current_user->description`.

```
    /**
11   * Core class used to implement the WP_User object.
12   *
13   * @since 2.0.0
14   *
15   * @property string $nickname
16   * @property string $description
17   * @property string $user_description
18   * @property string $first_name
19   * @property string $user_firstname
20   * @property string $last_name
21   * @property string $user_lastname
22   * @property string $user_login
23   * @property string $user_pass
24   * @property string $user_nicename
25   * @property string $user_email
26   * @property string $user_url
27   * @property string $user_registered
28   * @property string $user_activation_key
29   * @property string $user_status
30   * @property string $display_name
31   * @property string $spam
32   * @property string $deleted
33   */
```

Answer (score 0):

A-ha! I was already getting the rest of the current user info, but needed the proper "echo" line to get that biographical info field. Didn't realize it was called "description". So your code put me on the right path. All I needed to add to what I already had was:

```
echo 'User Description: ' . $current_user->description . '<br />';
```

Thank you muchly!

Comment: if you answer was the correct one you should choose it as such

Comment: @stoi2m1 based on her rep she may have to wait 2 days before she is allowed.